# Use Crypto JS CBC mode for decrypting and equivalent encrypting in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I have written the following Java code to encrypt a message/data. Currently it is using default encryption algorithm  (AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING). In JavaScript while decrypting I have used mode ECB. I read articles that ECB is not secure. So I need to move to CBC mode. But changing the mode is causing issue for me. Can you help me to change the mode in proper way so that it is compatible?

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class EncryptDecryptImpl {

    private static final String secretKey = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    private static final String mySecretKey = "my-secret-key";

    private static final String encryptionAlgorithm = "AES"; // need to use AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

    public static String encrypt(String data, String secret) {
        try {
            Key key = generateKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedValue);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) {
        try {
            Key key = generateKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException |
                BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Key generateKey(String secret) {
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret.getBytes());
        return new SecretKeySpec(decoded, encryptionAlgorithm);
    }

    public static String encodeKey(String key) {
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(key.getBytes());
        return new String(encoded);
    }

    public static String decodeKey(String key) {
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.getBytes());
        return new String(decoded);
    }

    public static String encodedBase64Key() {
        return encodeKey(secretKey); 
    }

    public static String decodedBase64Key(String encryptedSecretKey) {
        return decodeKey(encryptedSecretKey);
    }

    public static String aesEncryptedSecretKey() {
        return EncryptDecryptImpl.encrypt(mySecretKey, encodedBase64Key());
    }

    public static String aesDecryptedSecretKey() {
        return EncryptDecryptImpl.decrypt(aesEncryptedSecretKey(), encodedBase64Key());
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String encryptedSecretKey = EncryptDecryptImpl.aesEncryptedSecretKey(); // cipher text
```

JavaScript:

```
export const getSecretKey = () => {
  const encryptedBase64Key = 'bXVzdEJlMTZCeXRlc0tleQ==';
  const parsedBase64Key = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedBase64Key);
  const encryptedCipherText = getSessionStorageItem('uselessKey');
  let decryptedData = '';
  if (encryptedCipherText !== null) {
    decryptedData = AES.decrypt(encryptedCipherText, parsedBase64Key, {
      mode: mode.ECB, // need to use CBC
      padding: pad.Pkcs7
    })
  }
  return decryptedData.toString(enc.Utf8).toString();
}
```

Comment: Kindly note that other AES modes than ECB using "Initialization vectors" (IV) that should get generated randomly (that's the additional security) AND need to be known on decryption side as well, so a changed method cannot be "compatible". The IV need NOT be kept "hidden" so in most cases the IV is just prepended to the ciphertext on encryption side and stripped of on decryption side.

Comment: An example is described here: aes_cbc_256_string_encryption: https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/docs/aes_cbc_256_string_encryption.md showing the same functionality in Java and Javascript. Disclaimer: the author is me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roadmap has already been roughly outlined by M. Fehr in his comment. The CBC mode uses an IV. In general it has to be considered that a key/IV pair must not be applied more than once for security reasons. Therefore, the IV is usually randomly generated for each encryption.
The IV must be known during decryption. Hence, it is passed together with the ciphertext. However, since the IV is not secret, it is passed unencrypted, usually concatenated with the ciphertext in the order *IV | ciphertext*.

For this additional functionality the `encrypt()` method in the Java code has to be adapted as follows (for simplicity without exception handling):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
...
private static final String encryptionAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String keyAlgorithm = "AES";
...
public static String encrypt(String data, String secret) {
    Key key = generateKey(secret);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
    
    // Generate random IV, encrypt and concatenate IV and ciphertext
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));            
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] encryptedValue  = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + ciphertext.length).put(iv).put(ciphertext).array();
    
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedValue);
}
```

Note that in `generateKey()` with this change, `keyAlgorithm` must be used instead of `encryptionAlgorithm`.

On the JavaScript side, IV and ciphertext must be separated. CBC and PKCS7 are the default and do not need to be specified explicitly.
The ciphertext in the following CryptoJS code was generated with the above C# code and returns the original plaintext:

```js
const enc = CryptoJS.enc, lib = CryptoJS.lib, AES = CryptoJS.AES;

const encryptedBase64Key = 'bXVzdEJlMTZCeXRlc0tleQ==';
const parsedBase64Key = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedBase64Key);
const encryptedCipherText = 'FZ+lnxu9iZGkxmmBxae32ToSkoi+a2/BpzAd6HYnyBjFjCmpssVUVx9N+KQbhpU2ALpJVG8my25KTG6xg7AOXQ==';
const parsedCipherText = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedCipherText);

const iv = lib.WordArray.create(parsedCipherText.words.slice(0, 16 / 4));
const ciphertext = lib.WordArray.create(parsedCipherText.words.slice(16 / 4));

if (encryptedCipherText !== null) {
    decryptedData = AES.decrypt({ciphertext: ciphertext}, parsedBase64Key,{iv: iv});
}
      
console.log(decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Decryption in the Java code and encryption in the JavaScript code are to be changed analogously.

Note that old data must be migrated, because data encrypted with ECB mode cannot be decrypted with CBC mode.